# Data structure for fast insertion/deletion with sorting

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, tree, big-o

I'm desperately looking for a data structure allowing me to perform a good amount of insertions, almost as many deletions (probably same order of magnitude) and a very quick lookup of the highest (or the lowest, can live with either) value.
The deletion will always only affect the highest (or, again, lowest) value.
The problem is that the values have to be sorted and at any moment I could insert an element going at any point between other two. The only value I want to read (and delete) quickly, at any point is the maximum (or, again, minimum).

Is there anything you recommend?

Please give algorithmic complexity analysis for your proposed answers.

Comment: Please clarify your questions and comments. You say max insertion when what you seem to want is just insertion. Also, you say the values have to be sorted but you also say you only need to read the maximum value. Lastly, O(log n) is very close to O(1) but you seem to want faster. How many operations are you actually going to perform?

Comment: The operations should hover around 2 millions modifications per second. The vast majority will be max insertion, while a relatively small percentage (< 30%) will be insertion at an arbitrary position. As for the sorting, I don't care too much if giving that up can improve the algorithmic complexity of the other operations (see my comment below about my planned usage of pairing heaps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A heap is what you want.  Here's a simple implementation of a binary heap.  Whether it's a max heap or min heap depends on the comparison function you pass to it: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789

Note that a binary heap isn't the only way to build a heap.  But it's likely the easiest to build, and it performs well enough in most situations.

The items in the heap are not sorted, although they're ordered.  The only guarantee is that the highest (lowest) item is at the top of the heap and will be the one retrieved when you ask for the next item.

What you're building sounds like a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  There are other ways to implement a priority queue.  For example, I've seen a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) based priority queue that outperforms a heap-based priority queue.

If you really need O(1) insertion, then look into something like the [Fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap).

Comment: Fibonacci heaps are for people who do CS theory to claim the very best possible asymptotic running times. The constant sucks – use a pairing heap or something else instead.

Comment: given the nature of my problem, if I'll manage to develop a good implementation, either a fibonacci heap or - as suggested by user635541 - a pairing heap should do as they seem to be as close as I can get to my needs given the average frequency distribution of my operation types.

Answer (score 8):

Loos like you need a [Max-Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Supports O(log n) insertion, O(1) lookup of maximum and O(log n) deletion of maximum.

Comment: +1 but ideally I'd need O(1) max insertion and deletion as it's going to be performed probably more than anything else except for lookup.

Comment: @emaster: What do you mean by "max insertion"? Don't you just mean insertion? If you insert the max, then it will be O(1) in a heap. If you just meant insertion, then you could sort n numbers in linear time with your structure. There are Omega(nlogn) lower bounds for sorting if you only use comparisons...

Comment: @emaster70: O(log n) is pretty damn close to O(1) especially in a heap with a high branching factor. Or use a Fibonacci heap as suggested in Jim Mischel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This data structure is called [self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), and it's implemented in every language I used, except Borland Pascal.
Cost for all operations you mentioned (add/delete/lookup) is `O(logn)`. Min-max lookup can be `O(1)` too.

You can traverse all elements in sorted order in `O(n)`.

**edit**
I wasn't suggesting heap, because it doesn't satisfy *"have to be sorted"* requirement.

If you need to insert/delete/lookup **only max**, then I would suggest sorted array or linked list. Max insertion/deletion/lookup `O(1)` and all elements are already sorted.

Comment: +1 but same as above, O(log n) doesn't seem to be good enough for max insertion and deletion :(

Comment: Min-Max lookup in `O(1)`? You will need to do some tweaks I think.. (in AVL, RB-Tree,..) like having a node pointing to the *Min* / *Max*,..

Comment: @emaster70 For max insertion/deletion, simple array should work :)

Comment: @OscarMederos Well, storing pointer to max won't compromise complexity.